# Is Serre - Local algebra a good reference for an algebraic geometer?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Of course the question "what is a good commutative algebra book for an algebraic geometer" has been asked before, see [A good commutative algebra book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161229/a-good-commutative-algebra-book) and [Reference request: introduction to commutative algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37364/reference-request-introduction-to-commutative-algebra) for example.

Learning recently about intersection multiplicity of varieties and multiplicity of a singular point of a variety, i was led into thinking Serre - Local algebra might be a good buy. However, it is almost never mentioned in answers to the questions asked before.

So my question now is: is it a good idea to buy Serre's book if one wants to use it for algebraic geometry? Are there algebraic geometers here that have found it useful to have, in addition to more standard commutative algebra books?

Thanks!

Comment: I never read this book, but in general I can say Serre is a great writer.

Comment: @Abramo Yes i agree and that's also a reason for me to consider his book.