# Which commutative algebra book will be best suited while reading Igor Shafarevich book on Algebraic Geometry. [Self study]

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation

I am going to self study Algebraic Geometry by *Igor Shafarevich*'s book(Vol 1).

I know commutative algebra is a prerequisite for studying algebraic geometry.

There are lot of books on commutative algebra on web so I am confused.

**Which commutative algebra book will be best suited while reading Igor Shafarevich book on Algebraic Geometry.**

I have read Atiyah but I want a book which is more comprehensive and self sustained and suited for self studying.

Comment: There are more than enough links - start [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161229/a-good-commutative-algebra-book). Also, complex manifolds are useful for Shafarevich's book.

Comment: At one end of the spectrum there is Atiyah-Macdonald which is very terse (128 pages) and most of the connections to geometry are left to the exercises.  At the other is Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry*, which is much more verbose (785 pages) and often includes in the text itself motivation from geometry for concepts in commutative algebra.  I have found both very helpful because their approaches are so different.